# Why is the user number appended to links?

Tags: support

When I click on "link" under a question or an answer, the link that's produced ends with my user number. It works just as well if I remove that number (and the preceding slash). Why is this number being appended? Am I breaking something if I remove the number to shorten the link?

Comment: Maybe it is for things like "this is brought to you by 'joriki' and 'joriki' thinks you will like it?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that stripping off the user number will deprive you of the chance to earn the [announcer](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer), [booster](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster) and [publicist](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist) badges.  [This meta.SO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113638/for-what-purposes-is-my-user-id-used-when-sharing-a-link) seems to indicate that it has no other purpose.

Comment: See also [this meta.SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113638/) where your suspicion seems to be confirmed and [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.